# How to enable a disabled HTML form element when a choice from a combobox has been clicked?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this combobox in my HTML form where one of the choices when clicked will enable another combobox that as been disabled.

Here's the code of the combobox that contains a choice that would disable the other combobox

```
    Type of expense: <select name="expType" onchange="document.getElementById('expTypeVal').value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].text">
            <option value="direct labor"> direct labor </option>
            <option value="salary(sales)"> salary(sales) </option>
            <option value="salary (kitchen)"> salary(kitchen) </option>
            <option value="direct materials"> direct materials </option>
            <option value="indirect materials"> indirect materials </option>
            <option value="fare"> fare </option>
            <option value="kitchen supplies"> kitchen supplies </option>
            <option value="accounts payable"> accounts payable </option>
            <option value="rent"> rent </option>
            <option value="general"> general </option>
            <option value="repair/maint.(furn./fixt.)"> repair/maint.(furn./fixt.) </option>
            <option value="repair/maint.(equi./uten.)"> repair/maint.(equi./uten.) </option>
            <option value="repair/maint.(improv)"> repair/maint.(improv.) </option>
            <option value="drawings"> drawings </option>
    </select>
```

Whenever **accounts payable** choice is selected, I want a combobox to be enabled.

Here's the code for the other combobox. Note: this one's disabled.

```
<select disabled name="acctPayables" onchange="document.getElementById('acctPayVal').value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].text">
      <option value="N/A"> --- </option>
      <option value="random1"> random1 </option>
      <option value="random2"> random2 </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check it i have modified it a little bit

```
    <select disabled name="acctPayables" id="acctPayables">
          <option value="N/A"> --- </option>
          <option value="random1"> random1 </option>
          <option value="random2"> random2 </option>
    </select>   

    <select name="expType" id="expType" >
            <option value="direct labor"> direct labor </option>
            <option value="salary(sales)"> salary(sales) </option>
            <option value="salary (kitchen)"> salary(kitchen) </option>
            <option value="direct materials"> direct materials </option>
            <option value="indirect materials"> indirect materials </option>
            <option value="fare"> fare </option>
            <option value="kitchen supplies"> kitchen supplies </option>
            <option value="accounts payable"> accounts payable </option>
            <option value="rent"> rent </option>
            <option value="general"> general </option>
            <option value="repair/maint.(furn./fixt.)"> repair/maint.(furn./fixt.) </option>
            <option value="repair/maint.(equi./uten.)"> repair/maint.(equi./uten.) </option>
            <option value="repair/maint.(improv)"> repair/maint.(improv.) </option>
            <option value="drawings"> drawings </option>
    </select>

    <script>
        var select = document.getElementById("expType");
        var select1 = document.getElementById("acctPayables");
            select.onchange = function()
            {
                if(this.value == 'accounts payable')
                {
                    select1.removeAttribute('disabled');
                }
                else
                {
                    var att = document.createAttribute("disabled");
                    att.value = "";
                    select1.setAttributeNode(att);
                }
            }
    </script>
```

Please check the following jsfiddle code for the same

http://jsfiddle.net/otkcbbh2/

Comment: This worked when I tried the above code. Then I tried to put the script to my code, I also added the id="expType" and id="acctPayables" but it didn't work.

Comment: It doesn't say any error. The 2nd combobox does not disable when I select the accounts payable option.

Comment: I've checked and it worked. Then I applied to my own code and it worked too.

Comment: May I know the reason of remove from accept this one

Comment: sorry! Ididn't know I only need to accept one answer. I'm going to put it back. I also accepted the other one since it worked too. I'm really sorry.

Comment: It's ok and i think that another one is not working for me exactly what your question saying

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
$('select[name=expType]').change(function(){
  if($('select[name=expType] option:selected').val() === '-1') {
    $('select[name=acctPayables]').attr('disabled', true);
  } else {
    if($('select[name=acctPayables]').attr('disabled')) {
      $('select[name=acctPayables]').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
      $('select[name=acctPayables]').attr('disabled', true);
    }    
  }  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Type of expense: <select name="expType" onchange="document.getElementById('expTypeVal').value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].text">
                <option value="-1"> --- </option>
                <option value="direct labor"> direct labor </option>
                <option value="salary(sales)"> salary(sales) </option>
                <option value="salary (kitchen)"> salary(kitchen) </option>
                <option value="direct materials"> direct materials </option>
                <option value="indirect materials"> indirect materials </option>
                <option value="fare"> fare </option>
                <option value="kitchen supplies"> kitchen supplies </option>
                <option value="accounts payable"> accounts payable </option>
                <option value="rent"> rent </option>
                <option value="general"> general </option>
                <option value="repair/maint.(furn./fixt.)"> repair/maint.(furn./fixt.) </option>
                <option value="repair/maint.(equi./uten.)"> repair/maint.(equi./uten.) </option>
                <option value="repair/maint.(improv)"> repair/maint.(improv.) </option>
                <option value="drawings"> drawings </option>
        </select>
<select disabled name="acctPayables" onchange="document.getElementById('acctPayVal').value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].text">
      <option value="-1"> --- </option>
      <option value="random1"> random1 </option>
      <option value="random2"> random2 </option>
</select>
```

Add jQuery code like this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('select[name=expType]').change(function(){
     $('select[name=acctPayables]').attr('disabled', false);
   });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Where should I place the one you wrote on top?

Comment: In a document.ready block anywhere on the same page. You will want to wrap it in a scipt tag and a document ready function to insure the DOM node is present prior to attaching the events.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Seems like you are new in javascript and jquery. Jquery - http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp, Javascript - http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp. Follow these links for a good start

Comment: @Shuvro it works. How about I want it again to be disabled if the the choice was changed?

Comment: you need to use a toggle, another thing is you need to add a default field like the second combo box with a value of -1 for easier form validation and functionality. I'll update my code for better clarification.

Comment: check my updated answer and see if it works the way you want, the second combobox will get disabled if nothing from the first one is selected now.

Comment: @Shuvro I replaced the previous one with the one you have updated but it still does't get to disable if a different choice was selected.

Comment: sry for the late reply, i have updated the code, and saw you have found a solution too, good luck, happy coding.

Comment: How am I doing the exact opposite can you explain? Better point out what you find wrong here maybe. ;)